# Загрузка нескольких файлов на сервер

Tags: файлы, php, загрузка, upload, fileupload

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обработать файлы, загруженные через один инпут:

```
<input type='file' name='filedata' multiple>
```

Гугл рассказывает только про обработку файлов, загруженных несколькими инпутами:

```
<input type='file' name='filedata1'>  
<input type='file' name='filedata2'>  
<input type='file' name='filedata3'>
```

UPD: проблема в том, что $_FILES содержит только первый файл. print_r($_FILES):

```
Array ( [filedata] => Array ( [name] => sdfsdf.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => Z:\tmp\php3943.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 31815 ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

дык вы не правильное имя даете, `name='filedata[]'` должно быть

> Note that the "name" of the file input has brackets at the end of it. This isn't required per the spec but is required to process the multiple files.

Comment: Я вас обожаю!

Comment: таже фигня, если вы хотите много полей с одним именем, если задавать имя file[] , то они передадутся ввиде массива